# Embedding Google Keep in any way

Tags: iframe

I have a personal homepage I keep all my calenders and popular bookmarks set.  I have recently started using Google Keep more and would like to embed that into the same page.  I am tried keeping it simple and used an iframe but it will not load the content.

Is there another way to accomplish this or workaround?